# parse JSON string into array of objects Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios5

I have a JSON String returned from rest web service request,
I want to parse this string into Array of objects from determined class,
this is the JSON string

```
[
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": "Samer",
        "LastName": "Shame",
        "MobileNumber": "0991992993",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": "0991992994",
        "Name": "Abo Alshamat",
        "ID": 1
    },
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": "Ahmad",
        "LastName": "Ali",
        "MobileNumber": "0992993994",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": "0992993995",
        "Name": "AL-Kamal",
        "ID": 2
    },
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "MobileNumber": "0993377800",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "Name": "Abo-MAhmoud",
        "ID": 12
    },
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": "William",
        "LastName": "Ammar",
        "MobileNumber": "0993994995",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": "0993994996",
        "Name": "Four Season",
        "ID": 3
    },
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": "Ammar",
        "LastName": "William",
        "MobileNumber": "0999555777",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "Name": "uuuuu",
        "ID": 20
    },
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "MobileNumber": "0999888777",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "Name": "NewOneFromI2",
        "ID": 18
    },
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "MobileNumber": "0999998997",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": "0999999998",
        "Name": "JOURY",
        "ID": 4
    },
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "MobileNumber": "202020",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "Name": "TestTestRestaurant,Ammar,Hamed",
        "ID": 19
    }
]
```

the class I want to get instances from is:

```
@interface Restaurant : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *ID;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* FirstName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* LastName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* MobileNumber;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* simNumber;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* PhoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* Name;
@end
```

what is the best way to do that,excuse me maybe the question is from basic Knowledge but I am new to objective C

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest to implement an init method for your `Restaurant` class.

```
-(instancetype) initWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //initializations
        _validationCode = parameters[@"validationCode"]; // may be NSNull
        _firstName = [parameters[@"FirstName"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? @"" 
                     : parameters[@"FirstName"];
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note: the fact that you may have JSON Nulls, makes your initialization a bit elaborate. You need to decide how you want to initialize a property, when the corresponding JSON value is Null.

Your `parameters` dictionary will be the first level dictionary from the JSON Array which you got from the server.

First, create a JSON representation, that is a NSArray object from the JSON:

```
NSError* localError;
id restaurantsObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                        options:0 
                                                          error:&localError];
```

IFF this did not fail, your `restaurantsObjects` should now be an `NSArray` object containing the restaurants as `NSDictionary`s.

Now, it will be straight forward to create a `NSMutableArray` which will be populated with `Restaurant` objects:

```
NSMutableArray* restaurants = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary* restaurantParameters in restaurantsObjects) {
    Restaurant* restaurant = [Restaurant alloc] initWithParameters: restaurantParameters];
    [restaurants addObject:restaurant];
}
```

and finally, you may set a property `restaurants` in some controller:

```
self.restaurants = [restaurants copy];
```

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON have An array of dictionaies...
First convert your data to NSArray.

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;

NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&jsonError];
```

Now you have array of JSON dictionaries iterate.

```
  for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray){
      // Now you have dictionary get value for key
    NSString *firstName = (NSString*) [dic valueForKey:@"FirstName"];//We are casting to NSString because we know it will return a string. do this for every property...  
    }
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that `firstName` could be equal to `[NSNull null]` if '`FirstName`' is 'null' in the JSON. You actually don't know what it'll return (it could be a NSString, it could be an NSDictionary!), so extra care might be necessary, if you're not confident of how exactly the JSON will be formed (if you control the server side, it's less of a concern).

Comment: In this case we know that FirstName is string... So we are using like this other wise we can use NSObject... And if there is no FirstName... it will return nil...

Comment: Many of the `FirstName` in the example JSON are in fact `null`, which means `[NSNull null]` when deserialized. If `FirstName` doesn't appear at all, you would get `nil` when deserialized. If you're not careful, and the JSON is formatted differently than you expect/assume, you could end up with crashes (likely invalid selector).

Comment: `options` cannot be `nil`, use `0` instead.