# JSon array to core data entity

Tags: ios, json, core-data, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a cuestion about parsing a Json strings.
If i'm getting a string like:

```
[["AR","Argentina","flag_of_argentina","en","F","1"],
["AU","Australia","flag_of_‌​australia","en","B","4"]]
```

How can i save this string into an entity when normally i see Jsons that have something like this:

```
(
   (
    "Group_id": 1,
    "Date" : "2014-04-08",
    "Hour" : "18:00:00",
    "Location":"Guayaquil, Ecuador",
    "State" : A
),
...
```

If i have to make an array or something else to store it to the entity in core data how can i do it?

I hope my question is well made ​​and I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is that a paste of the real JSON? The second set of JSON isn't valid at all. And it looks like a log from `NSArray` really...

Comment: The first is the string i get the second i writed it as example.

The same string is used in android by the app of my friend and it runs good, i have some doubts about the use of it in ios.

Comment: Really sorry this is the string i get: [["AR","Argentina","flag_of_argentina","en","F","1"],["AU","Australia","flag_of_australia","en","B","4"]]

Comment: The first is real JSON, the second is an NSLog of an NSArray containing JSON data.  They look similar but not identical.  To convert between you use NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse JSON string into array of objects Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954637/parse-json-string-into-array-of-objects-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa Touch provides a built in class that helps you serialize this data. It's called `NSJSONSerialization`.

So, that looks to me like you have arrays within an array. First you're going to want to convert the NSString to NSData:

```
NSData *JSONdata = [yourJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then serialize it into an array:

```
NSArray *JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONdata options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Then you can access any subarray by writing:

```
NSArray *countryData = [JSONArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

And from there you can access the data that you need.

~

As for building JSON Data, you'll need to construct an NSMutableDictionary and populate it accordingly. Once you have that, use the same class `NSJSONSerialization` to convert it to a JSON string.